# How to Send User back to intended page in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am building a Laravel App where people can read Books.

I have middleware, that control access to the Book

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (!(auth()->user()->isBasic() || auth()->user()->isCouple() || auth()->user()->isFamily())) {
        return redirect(route('subscription-plan'));
    }
    return $next($request);

 }
```

In`web.php`

> To see the book and the details of the book

```
Route::get('/books/{book}', [BooksController::class, 'show'])->name('book')->middleware('verified');;
```

> To read the book

```
Route::middleware(['basic'])->group(function (){

Route::get('/read/{book_id}', [BooksController::class, 'read'])->name('read');

});
```

I have  3 roles

> Basic
>
> Couple
>
> Family
>
> Subscriber

If the logged-in user is a subscriber, it redirects to `/subscription-plan` when he tried to access `Read`.

After subscription, I want to be able to redirect after subscription to the book I was trying to read before I was redirected to `/subscription-plan`.

I was researching how to use `intended`

`redirect($this->redirectPath());`

`redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());`

But none of them is working.

Here is my final code

```
    public function handleGatewayCallback()
    {
      
     ...

     redirect()->intended();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are you doing on the subscription page.

*Just thinking that the user will leave the app complete the payment externally "paypal" and the payment processor will redirect the user back to your system on your fallback url , on success or not.*

If this is your case I don't think `intended`  will work for you..

My suggestion is to use session and store the URL where you want to return the user  after he has completed the payment on the subscription page.

Exmaple:

Store session key:

```
$request->session()->put('url_on_success', '/url-on-success');
```

Get the stored session:

```
$url = $request->session()->get('url_on_success');
```

Check : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session for more how to use sessions on Laravel.

Comment: Yes, the user will be redirected to external URL to complete the payment

Comment: then store your URL on success somewhere on your config files, .env , or use sessions.

Comment: I don't understand how to do this in config file. Can you please explain more

Comment: Check : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration to understand how to use .env or config files and access the variables on the system .